Quantifying effect-size and correlation between two data frames
I am conducting an effect-size analysis on dam release and downstream temperature measurments. To do this, I am comparing the gauge temperature (the temperature of the water released from the dam) with increasingly downstream loggers (temperature at various downstream sites). I had been conducting correlations, but the pattern I expected to see (correlation decreasing as you go more downstream) was not apparent. Here are the correlation plots I made, with S4 being the closest site to the gauge and S11 being the furthest.


What I think is happening is that correlation is matching up so much because of the diurnal fluctuations (i.e. any sort of stream data nearby would be highly correlated with the gauge), meaning that the correlation was not measuring what I was wanting. After asking a few questions, someone pointed me towards effect-size analysis and doing some research led me to Cohen's D, but after doing some calculations that also did not seem to give me the proper pattern I should be seeing.
The main goal is to find how much dam release is affecting downstream temperatures. I want to find the size of effect and in practicum, the effect should decrease with every increasingly downstream site I test (as more and more tributaries wash out the effect of the dam). I have been trying to find some sort of test or visual representation that can help answer this question. I am new to stats and r in general, so I need lots of help.
P.S. I also made some scatterplots with loess regression lines because someone suggested it, but I do not understand how to interpret them or even if they would help answer my question. I thought I would provide them here just in case though. I have also adjusted to data to account for the water travel time to each site. And the R values differ between the scatter and line plots because I used spearman for the top ones and the pearson for the bottom ones just to see if I could see a significant difference (but I could not).
Thanks for any help!



How far away from the dam are the two stations? How frequently is water released from the dam? You will have a huge number of confounding variables in a simple regression/correlation (e.g. time of day, midday = warm, night = cold) that you'll need to control for as well.

I do understand that and I was going to run multivariate tests after completing this. I have adjusted the travel time, and the dates are also lined up, so the main variable is the dam release and I am trying to find the association / effect size.

I suspect that you were directed to look at effect size instead of statistical significance because you're looking for a signal that seems to be small relative to the diurnal/seasonal fluctuations. My recommendation would be to look at the place where a jump in temperature signal should be largest (a single dam release event for station 4). If you can't see anything there then your effect size is essentially zero and your question is answered (at least for that event). I would also consider calculating a temperature difference between the gauge and the station instead of absolute values.
